# Kubernetes headless service A Record round robin

Tags: dns, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, skydns

I'm trying to create two kubernetes services, one which is a loadbalancer with a cluster IP, and another which is a headless (no cluster IP), but instead returns an A record round robin collection of the pod ip addresses (as it should do, according to http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#headless-services).

I need to do this because I need a dynamic collection of pod ip's in order to do auto clustering and service discovery.

My services look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
    tier: messaging
spec:
  ports:
  - name: amqp
    port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
    tier: messaging
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-cluster
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq
    tier: messaging
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: amqp
    port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq
    tier: messaging
```

With these two services, i get the following:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME               CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP       PORT(S)     AGE
rabbitmq           10.23.255.174   <none>            5672/TCP    7m
rabbitmq-cluster   None            <none>            5672/TCP    7m
```

And DNS (from another pod) for the cluster IP works:

```
[root@gateway-3738159135-a7wp9 app]# nslookup rabbitmq.td-integration
Server:     10.23.240.10
Address:        10.23.240.10#53

Name:   rabbitmq.td-integration.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.23.255.174
```

However, the dns for the 'headless' service, doesn't return:

```
[root@gateway-3738159135-a7wp9 app]# nslookup rabbitmq-cluster.td-integration
Server:     10.23.240.10
Address:        10.23.240.10#53

** server can't find rabbitmq-cluster.td-integration: NXDOMAIN
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like there is no pod matching these labels within your cluster, therefore the DNS query doesn't return anything. This is expected.

Start the corresponding pods and you should see a list of A records.

Please be aware that these A records are not shuffled as far as I know, so your clients are expected to consume the DNS answer and perform their own round robin.